# Можно ли использовать свой компаратор во встроенной сортировке в Python 3.5, и, если можно, то как?

Tags: python-3.x

Можно ли использовать свой компаратор во встроенной сортировке в Python 3.5, и, если можно, то как?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, можно. Вам нужно написать функцию, которая принимает элемент множества и возвращает какое-то значений, по которому и будет происходить сортировка. Также можно использовать встроенную функция, например, `len()`.

Нужно передать имя функции в метод `sort()` или `sorted()` как параметр `key`.

Например, отсортируем числа по первой цифре:

```
def first_number(a):
    return int(str(a)[0])
lst = [635, 3214, 15, 23, 9, 10]
lst.sort(key=first_number)
print(lst)
```

Вывод:

```
[15, 10, 23, 3214, 635, 9]
```

То же самое можно реализовать с помощью lambda-функции:

```
lst = [635, 3214, 15, 23, 9, 10]
lst.sort(key=lambda x: int(str(x)[0]))
print(lst)
```

Выведет то же самое.

Теперь сделаем сортировку по длине строки с помощью встроенной функции:

```
lst = ['aaaaaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'cccccc', 'd']
lst.sort(key=len)
print(lst)
```

Вывод:

```
['d', 'bbbbb', 'cccccc', 'aaaaaaaa']
```